# Pycharm debugger No module named 'spacy.tokens'

Tags: debugging, pycharm, spacy

I have the following code: 
`from spacy.tokens.doc import Doc`
When I am using run in pycharm everything works fine but when I use the debug I get the following:

```
in <module>
    from spacy.tokens.doc import Doc
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.tokens'
```

If I do only `import spacy` everything works fine.

Comment: Is it possible you have different versions of spaCy in different environments or something?

Comment: Checked it and I use spacy 3.1.2 in all environments

Comment: maybe you have different Python interpreters and don't have spaCy installed in one env. Does just `import space` work in all envs? Also is `import sys; print(sys.executable)` the same everywhere?

Comment: @polm23 Yes import spacy works in all envs and when I print the executable path it's the same one

Comment: I have no idea then, sorry.